# Shell Error xargs: terminated by signal 11

Tags: linux, shell, segmentation-fault, xargs

I'm working with FIND command with directory exclusion on an image compression tool jpeg-recompress and used xargs to speed up the process.

The command line is:

```
find /path/dir -type f -name '*.jpg' -not -path '*/imdb/*' | xargs -P 50 -I {} jpeg-recompress --quality high --min 60 --method smallfry --strip \{} \{} \;
```

Error occured after some minutes:

```
xargs: jpeg-recompress: terminated by signal 11
```

It's only happened when working on large directory which consists of hundreds of thousands images. I have searched that signal 11 related with segmentation faults, but I don't understand them quite well. The only thing I know is that presumably I am trying to access some memory I shouldn't.

Please help, I don't really understand the code and don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It just means that one of the `jpeg-recompress` runs on segmentation fault on certain conditions. This is not directly related to xargs, except - maybe - that this bug in jpeg-recompress shows up more likely if many recompress processes are run in parallel. You could try to run it with `-P 1` a couple of times (though this will require some patience from your side), and if the error is gone, you know at least that the error is caused by parallelizing.

Comment: @user1934428 Try your suggestion to lower the parallelizing to -P 25. Will report back tomorrow if the error still exist.

Comment: @user1934428 Still give me same error. I lower it again to -P 10.

Comment: Why not to `-P 1` as I suggested?  If this works, you can still go upwards with the parallelism. If it doesn't work, we know that the problem is not the parallelism and we can search somehwhere else.

Comment: Yeah, today I lower it to -P 1, Still same error xargs: jpeg-recompress: terminated by signal 11 find: ‘standard output’: Broken pipe find: write error

Comment: And I guess if you run jpeg-recompress without xargs (to a single argument), you don't get the error, right? What happens if you don't use `-P` at all?

Comment: Did you see [this one](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/jpeg-archive/issues/24)?

Comment: @user1934428 without -P it will definitely halt my SSH session on large directory. Thanks for the link anyway. I noticed the error more related to  big size images than number of images processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from `jpeg-recompress` not from `xargs`: `jpeg-recompress` dies due to a SIGSEGV. Segmentation faults usually only occur if there is a bug in the program - typically a wrong pointer.

I am confident that this is due to a bug in `jpeg-recompress` which is triggered by a single, slightly corrupt jpeg-file (or which just happens to have a format not expected by `jpeg-recompress`).

This also explain why you only see this on a large directory which consists of hundreds of thousands images: One of these is slightly corrupt.

One way to identify the file is to use GNU Parallel's `--joblog` and `--halt`:

```
find /path/dir -type f -name '*.jpg' -not -path '*/imdb/*' |
  parallel --joblog my.log --halt now,fail=1 jpeg-recompress --quality high --min 60 --method smallfry --strip \{} \{}
```

Then you should find the name of the broken file on the last line of `my.log`.

If you think there may be more corrupt files:

```
find /path/dir -type f -name '*.jpg' -not -path '*/imdb/*' |
  parallel --joblog my.log jpeg-recompress --quality high --min 60 --method smallfry --strip \{} \{}
grep -P '\t11\t' my.log
```

Comment: Today I start to do your suggestion. It will take sometime to a conclusion. I'm able to log the corrupted files using single `--halt now,fail=1` several times. But when log multiple corrupt files and use command `grep -P '\t11\t' my.log` it giving me some non corrupted images. Can you tell what this line `'\t11\t'` actually do?

Comment: `'\t11\t'` searches for TAB 11 TAB, which is SIGSEGV. It may give a few false positives if other columns contain 11.

Comment: Please keep the corrupt files and file a bug report to the developers of jpeg-recompress, so they can exit gracefully instead of segfaulting.

Comment: your `parallel --joblog` can be my  temporary solution and avoid the segfaulting in the process. I have filled a bug report as your suggestion. Thank you very much for your help.